# How to test MVP presenter method which has database operation

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have implement unit test with MVP Architecture and every thing went well
with `Junit4` and `Mokito`

But my problem my that when i need to test methods which has database operation

i'm facing two issue

1-getting null pointer Exception when using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`
 and mocking the Presenter and View

2-using `InstrumentationTestCase` and MockContext i'm able to open the data base with no error but when i call verify on database related method the test success but in the coverage i see that this method in the presenter is not covered

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can't really provide a detailed answer, but in general, you could use `Robolectric` (which uses a real SQLite db) in order to unit-test classes which depend on `SQLite` database.

Keep in mind, though, that these tests might be slow. In my practice, a unit test that uses SQLite and run by `Robolectric` test runner can take up to 10 seconds and more.

Comment: Thanks man for your response actually i didn't that much because i didn't knew how to do it what i'm doing now is UI with some data to simulate those method using InstrumentationTest idk if that correct approach but better than nothing , it would be great if u share any tutorial for using sqlite with robolectric

Comment: @Tony, take a look at official robolectric's tutotials. You don't need to do anything special, just 1) run your test with Robolectric's test runner 2) Use Robolectric's context (Runtime.application) instead of Android's context